# how to display list as table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have a list of items with different content floated left, I need to display them as a row.

```
<ul>
<li>small content..</li>
<li>medium Content..</li>
<li>large content..</li>
..
<!-- many item random contnet -->
</ul>
```

I would like to display the list items in a row.
row height depends on max height item in row, 
How to get it?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CmkSb/)

Comment: I think this is not a good idea. I would instead do it with divs.

Comment: @Jai `<table>` is also a good element.

Comment: I am adding elements dynamically so I cannot sort them as table.

Comment: Google "unordered list as table row" and click the first result.

Comment: Don't !!! If you have table content use <table>. If you care about semantics, else use <span> or whatever

Comment: @AxentePaul That doesn't make any sense at all.  Yes, if the content is tabular, it belongs in a table.  Just because a particular piece of data isn't tabular doesn't mean there aren't tags that are semantically appropriate for the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should go with javascript to set clear:both to row overflow element.

```
 var ch=$("#container").width();

    var itemsPerRow=Math.floor(ch/102);

    var itemsCount=$("#contentpane li").length;
    var loopRound=Math.floor(itemsCount/itemsPerRow);

    for(var i=1;i<loopRound+1;i++)
    {
        var nextFirstItem=i*itemsPerRow+1;

        $("#contentpane li:nth-child("+ nextFirstItem  +")").css({"clear":"both"});
    }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CmkSb/9/)

Answer (score 4):

Add `display:table-cell` so it acts as table column. remove `float:left` as well.

```
#contentpane{}
#contentpane li{
    padding:10px;
    width:80px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:table-cell
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CmkSb/2/)**

---

**CASE 2**

In case you need it with auto height then use the below `white-space:nowrap;` method

```
ul#contentpane{
    width:100%;  
    white-space:nowrap;

}
#contentpane li{
    padding:10px;
    width:80px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal !important;
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/CmkSb/4/)** ||  **[DEMO (Vertically aligned to the top)](http://jsfiddle.net/CmkSb/6/)**

Comment: _Why_ is “float:left required” …?

Comment: I should display the content fit to container

Comment: @user1834809 In this case you actually need Jquery masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/ . Anyways good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
    display: table-row;
}

ul  > li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Note that you should have a wrapper with `display: table` in order to built a complete table representation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var maxHeight = 0;
 $("#contentpane li").each(function( index ) {
     var height = $(this).height();
     if(height  > maxHeight){
         maxHeight =height;
      }
 });

$("#contentpane li").css("height",maxHeight);
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dgNtr/)

Answer (score 0):

Set height to the li.

```
#contentpane{

}
#contentpane li{
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    width:80px;
    height:180px;
    overflow:auto;
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/bsuu6/)**

Comment: On table-cell elements, height only indicates a minimum height.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the float and use inline-block instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/CmkSb/10/

```
#contentpane li{
    padding:10px;
    width:80px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```